# How to create a Xcode 6 workspace that includes 2 iOS Projects and an iOS Dynamic Framework project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, frameworks

I'm trying to create one Xcode workspace that includes 3 projects:
- 2 different iOS apps
- One dynamic framework project

The two iOS apps should use the framework.

Sounds very easy and reasonable thing to do, but I just can't seem to make it to work.
When I add the framework to the iOS app target as linked library, the build process works but when running I get an exception that the framework could not be found.
If I go to the Embed Binaries -> click add -> choose the framework from the framework project, nothing happens (the embed binaries section stays empty.
I tried to do first add the framework as linked library, then add it to the embed binaries. Now compilation doesn't work (can't find the framework).

What am I missing? Every single example in the documentation shows how to add a framework as a new target under the same project. But that's doesn't help. I want the framework to be a separate project that a team can work on separately.

Comment: Does this help?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28304263/how-to-embed-private-objective-c-framework-into-ios-app-on-xcode-6-with-workspac

Answer (score 0):

Open Xcode, so you can see Xcode in the menu bar.
Then go File>New>Workspace.

I believe you just drag and drop other projects into the workspace.

I've never really used a workspace, although I have made one before.

Comment: If you have not tried it then how can you be sure this is the answer ?